# OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded when filtering multiple partitions

Tags: apache-spark

I have a partiotoned hive table. Partition format is `yyyyMMdd_P` where `yyyyMMdd` is date and `P` is region and can have 9 values(A, B, C etc)

I need all types for one date.

When I try one partiton

```
spark.table(TABLE_NAME).filter($"date_region" === "20180801_A")
```

It works fine.

But when I try all 9 I get `OutOfMemoryError`.

I tried

```
$"date_region" rlike "20180801_*"
substring($"date_region",1,8) === "20180801"
$"date_region".isin(list:_*)
```

I have the impression spark is trying to read all dates, but am not sure. Each partition is relatively small (2-4 GB)

I assign following resources for the task.

```
--num-executors 10 \
--executor-cores 5 \
--driver-memory 4G \
--executor-memory 8G \
```

How can I read the table?

PS I get the error when I try .show in spark-shell or try to write the result to disc.

Comment: When do you encounter OOM error? Which action are you invoking? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @phil It's when I try `.show` or to write the result to disc

Comment: Are you doing a .show() without argument or .show(nb_lines) where nb_lines is large? Are you trying to write on hdfs or on disc with a .collect() ?

Comment: @Furry I tried show without arguments and I tried writing both with and without coalesce. I didn't try collect.

Comment: try increasing your executor memory

Comment: Can you just count your data or something like that(without filtering)?